# 2 differently filtered bindings from same source, coming out with same results (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

So, I created an example to show the issue I'm having with my WPF application at the moment. First I have a restaurant object, containing names, and a selected variable which I intend to bind to a CheckBox.Checked value. I attach this to a ComboBox and a ListBox as their ItemsSource.

```
public class Restaurants
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Boolean Selected { get; set; }
}

rItems = new List<Restaurants>();
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Alice Fazoolis", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Applebees", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Caseys", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Cracker Barrell", Selected = false }); 
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "East Side Marios", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Golden Griddle", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Harveys", Selected = true });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Imperial Buffet", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Jack Astors", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Kakimono", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Kelseys", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Little Ceasars", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Lonestar", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Makimono", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Mandarin", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "McDonalds", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Milestones", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Montanas", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Moxies", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Mr. Sub", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "None", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Other (Specify)", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Pizza Pizza", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Spring Rolls", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Subway", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "St. Louis Bar & Grill", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Sunset Grill", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Swiss Chalet", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Tatemono", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "The Keg", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "The Melting Pot", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "The Outback", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Tim Hortons", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Wendys", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Wimpys Diner", Selected = false });
rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Quiznos", Selected = false });
cboSelections.ItemsSource = rItems;
lstAnswers.ItemsSource = rItems;
```

I then have two filtering methods. One to select all the values that start with a specific letter, and the second to grab all items that are selected. On my screen I generate a keyboard of each starting letter. When a letter is selected, I filter the list and only display those results. The selected group will be placed into a ListBox

```
private bool LetterFilter(object item){
    if (((Restaurants) item).Name.ToUpper().StartsWith(LetterClicked))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

private bool SelectedFilter(object item){
    if (((Restaurants)item).Selected)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
 }
```

When Window_Loaded, I'm filtering based on a Letter that I know will have no results for the ListBox. And telling my selections box to grab any selected values. (I want the screen empty on startup)

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionView viewCBO = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(cboSelections.ItemsSource);
    viewCBO.Filter = SelectedFilter;
    CollectionView viewLST = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstAnswers.ItemsSource);
    LetterClicked = "-";
    viewLST.Filter = LetterFilter;
}`

private void btnLetter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstAnswers.ItemsSource);
    LetterClicked = ((Button)sender).Content.ToString();
    view.Filter = LetterFilter;
}
```

The problem is that, when I load either filter, I end up getting the same values in both viewCBO and viewLST. So, for example, if I select "L", I am seeing "Little Caesars" and "Lonestar" in both, despite not selecting either one.

What I require is for viewLST to have the values for my list of answers filtered by letter, and for viewCBO a separate list for all those that are Selected = true. But Coming from the same source.

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: So just for clarification: you have a bunch of letter buttons, a list box that displays all of the restaurants that start with the letter whose button was clicked, and a combo box that contains those restaurants that were selected in the list box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will have the same source if you use the static method with same list for CollectionViewSource. Refer the below code.

```
<Window x:Class="MSDN15Jan2015_Learning.Window4"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window4" Height="600" Width="300">
<StackPanel> 
    <TextBox x:Name="txt" Height="20" Width="200"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn" Click="btn_Click" Content="Letter Refresh"/>
   <ListBox x:Name="lstAnswers" Height="200" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChanged="lstAnswers_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Selected}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name" x:Name="cboSelections" Height="20"/>
</StackPanel>
```

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MSDN15Jan2015_Learning
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window4.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window4 : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<Restaurants> rItems;
        string LetterClicked;
        public Window4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += Window4_Loaded;
            rItems = new ObservableCollection<Restaurants>();
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Alice Fazoolis", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Applebees", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Caseys", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Cracker Barrell", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "East Side Marios", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Golden Griddle", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Harveys", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Imperial Buffet", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Jack Astors", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Kakimono", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Kelseys", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Little Ceasars", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Lonestar", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Makimono", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Mandarin", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "McDonalds", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Milestones", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Montanas", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Moxies", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Mr. Sub", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "None", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Other (Specify)", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Pizza Pizza", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Spring Rolls", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Subway", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "St. Louis Bar & Grill", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Sunset Grill", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Swiss Chalet", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Tatemono", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "The Keg", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "The Melting Pot", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "The Outback", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Tim Hortons", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Wendys", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Wimpys Diner", Selected = false });
            rItems.Add(new Restaurants() { Name = "Quiznos", Selected = false });           
        }
        ICollectionView viewCBO;
        ICollectionView viewLST;
        void Window4_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            viewCBO = new CollectionViewSource { Source = rItems }.View;
            viewCBO.Filter = SelectedFilter;
            viewLST = new CollectionViewSource { Source = rItems }.View;
            LetterClicked = "-";
            viewLST.Filter = LetterFilter;
            cboSelections.ItemsSource = viewCBO;
            lstAnswers.ItemsSource = viewLST;
        }
        private bool LetterFilter(object item)
        {
            if (((Restaurants)item).Name.ToUpper().StartsWith(LetterClicked))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        private bool SelectedFilter(object item)
        {
            if (((Restaurants)item).Selected)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {   
            LetterClicked =txt.Text;
            viewLST.Filter = null;
            viewLST.Filter = LetterFilter;
            viewLST.Refresh();
        }

        private void lstAnswers_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            viewCBO.Refresh();
        }
    }

    public class Restaurants:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; OnNotify("Name"); }
        }

        private bool selected;

        public bool Selected
        {
            get { return selected; }
            set { selected = value; OnNotify("Selected"); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnNotify(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Terrific answer. Very easy to understand :)

Comment: Hmm, one question. What if my listbox is using an ItemTemplate, formatting each row as a CheckBox, which I'm trying to set as either Checked or Unchecked depending on that Selected field. It tells me that I cannot use ItemTemplate and DisplayMemberPath. Won't compile.

Comment: Refer the ListBox Code.

Comment: Many thanks. I have a lot to learn about WPF controls. Appreciated